# Having a page appear larger when viewed on phones?

Tags: html, css, mobile, zooming, viewport

having finished a little webpage and giving it a basic layout, I decided to test what it'd look like using a mobile browser. So I installed the Android SDK with emulator, and as it turns out, the couple of elements on the page appear really small. I'd estimate about 80% of the page is currently empty background by default. However, when I zoom, it looks great, because the `width:height` ratio matches the phone's screen. That said, I'd prefer to leave the page unchanged, it just needs to be bigger as a whole.

**Is there a way I can make my page appear zoomed-in on by default?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

for an initial scale of 1:1, add this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Sweet, that worked out really well. Just what I needed, thank you!